# What are the signs of spiritual awakening?

Tags: spiritual-level, spirituality

What is Spiritual awakening? Some say the repetition of numericals like 11111 , 2222 etc is the most prominent and first sign of spiritual awakening.

Are these things real? Is there any books on the same?

Source: http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/spiritual-awakening-signs

Thank you.

Comment: Well these are initial signs that it's time ... rest is up to the individual to realize this and work consistently towards that.

Comment: Do u want to know about the signs of spiritual awakening which is accomplished through Yoga?

Comment: the website you reference has no relation to Hinduism or Eastern mysticism. Looks like the blind leading the blind. Read Raja Yoga (includes a translation of Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms) in Volume 2 available here - http://www.advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php

Answer (score 6):

The  exact signs of Spiritual Awakening  are precisely   described in [**Svetasvatara Upanishad**](http://esamskriti.com/essays/Svetasvatara-UP-TNS-Complete.pdf)  – **Chapter two – Verse 13   - Page no 21  -**

> लघुत्वमारोग्यमलोलुपत्वं वर्णप्रसादं स्वरसौष्ठवं च |
>  गन्ध: शुभो
>   मूत्रपुरीषमल्पं योगप्रवृत्तिं प्रथमा वदन्ति || 2.13||
>
> laghutvam ārogyam alolupatvaṃ varṇaprasādaḥ svarasauṣṭhavaṃ ca 
>   gandhaḥ śubho mūtrapurīṣam alpaṃ yogapravṛttiṃ prathamāṃ vadanti //
>   2.13 //
>
> The precursors of perfection in yoga, they say, are lightness and
>   healthiness of the body, absence of desire, clear complexion, and
>   pleasantness of voice, sweet odor and slight excretions.

The previous Mantra told us that Pranayama awakens the subtle powers in the seeker. **This Mantra gives the details about the effect of such awakening on the body** such as lightness, clear complexion etc. But it should always be noted that these are only initial stages and Pranayama should not be considered as the final objective. It is only a purification process for the final goal of concentration and self-absorption in Brahman.

---

Another Translation from  [**Vedanta Spiritual Library**](http://www.celextel.org/upanishads/krishna_yajur_veda/svetasvatara.html)
II-13:

> II-13: It is said that the first signs of entering Yoga are lightness
>   of body, health, thirstlessness of mind, clearness of complexion, a
>   beautiful voice, an agreeable odour and scantiness excretions.

Comment: So you mean to say that Yoga leads to spiritual awakening?

Comment: Well am just seeking answer myself :)

Comment: Yes "Yoga leads to spiritual awakening"

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to answer this without the Yoga-perspective.

Yoga can be of two kinds: `Hatha` and `Raja`, where Hatha Yoga mainly focuses on making the body strong and disease free, which provides the platform for further spiritual progress. And Raja Yoga is more of meditation & less of cumbersome physical activities that finally leads to spiritual awakening.

But since without a healthy body spiritual advancements can not be made these two are deeply inter-linked. And, as the following verse says:

> Hatham vinā rājayogho rājayogam vinā hathah
>  Na sidhyati tato
>   yughmamānishpatteh samabhyaset||
>
> .............
>
> No success in Râja Yoga without Hatha Yoga, and no success in Hatha
>   Yoga without Râja Yoga. One should, therefore, practise both of these
>   well, till complete success is gained.

So, first, i am giving the preliminary signs that indicate that the Sadhaka is achieving success in Hatha Yoga.

> Vapuh krśatvam vadane prasannatā
>  Nādasphutatvam nayane
>   sunirmale
>  Aroghatā bindujayoaghnidīpanam
>   Nādīviśuddhirhathasiddhilakshanam||
>
> ..........
>
> When the body becomes lean, the face glows with delight, Anâhatanâda
>   manifests, and eyes are clear,  body is healthy, bindu under control, and appetite increases, then one should know that the Nâdîs are purified and
>   success in Hatha Yoga is approaching.

In Yoga Sadhana they talk of four Avasthas, that the Sadhaka experiences one after another, with the first such Avastha is the one that gives the preliminary signs of success.

> Ārambhaścha ghataśchaiva tathā parichayoapi cha
>  Nishpattih
>   sarvayogheshu syādavasthāchatushtayam||
>
> ...........
>
> In all the Yogas, there are four states: (1) ârambha or 
>   the preliminary, (2) Ghata, or the state of a jar, (3) Parichaya
>   (known), (4) nispatti (consumate.)

And, the signs of the Arambha Avastha are as follows:

> Divyadehaścha tejasvī divyaghandhastvaroghavān
>  Sampūrnahrdayah
>   śūnya ārambhe yogavānbhavet
>
> ............
>
> In the ârambha, a Yogî's body becomes **divine, glowing, healthy, and
>   emits a divine smell.** The whole of his  heart becomes void.

Some, further signs are as follows:

> When the Brahma granthi (in the heart) is pierced through by
>   Prânâyâma, then a sort of happiness is experienced in the vacuum of
>   the heart, **and the anâhat sounds, like various tinkling sounds of
>   ornaments, are heard in the body.**

**NOTE**: All these verses are taken from the Yoga Treatise called [Hatha Yoga Pradipika.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika)

Some further signs are given below. They are taken from another Yoga Treatise called the Shiva Samhita:

> But so long as he does not gain it, let him practise observing all the
>   rules and restrictions laid down above. From the perfection of
>   pranayama, **follows decrease of sleep, excrements and urine** (43)
>
> The truth perceiving Yogi becomes free from disease, and sorrow or
>   affliction. **He never gets (putrid) perspiration, saliva** and intestinal
>   worms.
>
> **Shiva Samhita's Chapter 2 verses.**

Answer (score 0):

We are always getting different hints as we go through the ups and downs of life. Each of these hints are signs for awakening the deep spiritual person within us.

As normal human beings, we tend to ignore all these signs till one wakes us up. This awakening sign is different for different people. In my case, it was visions of the future during the period of just waking up, along with an overwhelming sadness that I could not explain, even though life was perfect at that point.

This made me want to go back to a set of spiritual practices that were imbibed in me as a child. I am still on the journey (as are we all) but now am acutely aware of the awakening.

Comment: Can you shed more light on 'spiritual practices' you followed?

Comment: I used to do the [Suryabehdana pranayam](https://www.yogajournal.com/poses/single-nostril-breath) followed by [Naadi Shuddi] (http://www.yogawiz.com/pranayama/nadi-suddhi.html) followed by [Yajur Sandhyavandanam] (http://www.rishikeshyogsansthan.org/images/library/Yajurveda-Sandhyavandanam-English.pdf)  I came back to the rhythm of doing the same, along with joining a meditation class held once a week on Saturdays in a Temple near me. Now, this is where I went back to my roots - each person is different and so are our roots. I feel if we go back and search ourselves, we will find that set.